# Several int3 in a row

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm using x64dbg to inspect the disassembly of a .DLL.

At several points in the assembly I see several Int3 instructions in a row.

```
00007FFA24BF1638 | CC                       | int3                                    |
00007FFA24BF1639 | CC                       | int3                                    |
00007FFA24BF163A | CC                       | int3                                    |
00007FFA24BF163B | CC                       | int3                                    |
00007FFA24BF163C | CC                       | int3                                    |
00007FFA24BF163D | CC                       | int3                                    |
00007FFA24BF163E | CC                       | int3                                    |
00007FFA24BF163F | CC                       | int3                                    |
```

This instruction is used for debugging / break points right? So then why are there so many in a row, and why is there any at all considering this DLL was compiled with a release configuration VC++.

Comment: Maybe it's there to prevent you from debugging at ease

Comment: That's characteristic of the Microsoft C/C++ compiler. It uses breakpoint instructions (INT3) to pad code to alignment boundaries, as Jester's answer says.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably just padding, they won't ever be executed. I assume the next function begins at `00007FFA24BF1640` which is 16 byte aligned, and the preceding function presumably ends before these instructions.

Comment: Using an instruction like that as the filler for regions that are never supposed to be executed may possibly help prevent speculative execution from wasting / resources.  Usually padding like that comes after a `ret`, but maybe an indirect-branch target mispredict could have the CPU trying to execute there.  A bad choice for padding after a `ret` would be something like `add ax, 1024`, because Intel CPUs would stall when decoding the block that included the ret.  (The operand-size prefix changes the length of the instruction, because it means imm16 instead of imm32.  Intel doesn't like that).